# adwords universal campaign for app

Tags: android, google-play, google-ads-api

I've created a universal apps campaign from my AdWords Developer account. The campaign went off and produced impressions as I expected and many clicks though though .... I pay? But if you can set a cost for download in the campaign, and what does that mean?
I've created a new "Display Network Only - Mobile App Installs" campaign, but this also makes me pay for clicks. And we know very well that clicks are not all true, so I pay for nothing.
Also on 1600 hypothetical clicks no downloads that I do not think can really be seen since the app is done well and it is well explained to what it is intended for and for who it is destined.

This is a result of the universal campaign for App

```
    Campagna    Clic    Impr.   CTR CPC medio   Costo   Conversioni Costo/conv. Tasso conv. Tutte le conv.  Visualizzazioni Percentuale visualizzazione CPV medio   Installazioni   Azioni in-app   Costo/installazione Costo/azione in-app
    Campagna n. 1   1.643   157.159 1,05%   0,02 €  33,27 € 0,00    0,00 €  0,00%   0,00    0   0,00%   0,00 €  0,00    0,00    0,00 €  0,00 €
```

As you can see, I've already spent 32 € for getting 1600 clicks, but from what I understood, obviously bad, I would have to pay 0.30 € for each installation.

Help me to shed light on the matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question, its a marketing question.  And even then I don't think its an answerable question.  Maybe the ad was just bad?

Comment: No, no has been deliberately posted here because I'm crazy and I have no answer anywhere. Please do not close.

Comment: That doesn't make it any more on topic

Comment: Can you suggest where to ask? I've already tried the AdWords forum without getting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob is not a kind of ad supplier that offers ads on a pay-per-install basis. It is pay-per-click. Meaning every click on an ad:

- costs you money
- gives the person who displayed the ad money

(Then google gets some of the money as well, but I am not sure on the percentages there)

Meaning your ad:

- Tries to get people to download the ad
- Costs/pays per click

As already mentioned, even with the mobile app install ad, that is just the classification of the ad and is probably only used to show personalized ads.

So the pay per click part is what you signed up for when you created a new campaign with admob. If you want pat-per-install ads you have to look to a different ad supplier(don't ask me for tips because it is off-topic and I don't know of any. But google does)

As for the reason you don't get any installs could be anything from it not looking like something the person who clicked the ad would install when seen in Google play, it could be bad but the ad made it look better than it actually was, the person who clicked isn't interested, etc. There are **many reasons** why you don't get any installs

Comment: Thanks for the polite answer though I do not really solve the problem since the campaign is an AdWords created from the developer console and that it should have been pay per install and not pay per click. I need the pay per install otherwise I bleed unnecessarily.